# Samba Print Server not uploading drivers to clients

Tags: printing, samba, active-directory

I am running Samba4 on Ubuntu 18.04 as a AD/DC.  I am also using this server as a CUPS print server that will host 4 printers. Everything is configured and running with the following smb.conf file:

```
[global]
        dns forwarder = 10.0.10.1
        netbios name = ACD1
        realm = PREMPROVSOL.LOC
        server role = active directory domain controller
        workgroup = PREMPROVSOL
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
        template shell = /bin/bash
        winbind use default domain = true
        winbind offline logon = false
        winbind nss info = rfc2307
        winbind enum users = yes
        winbind enum groups = yes
        vfs objects = acl_xattr
        map acl inherit = yes
        store dos attributes = yes

[print$]
        comment = Network Printer Drivers Container
        path = /usr/share/samba/drivers
        read only = yes
        guest ok = yes
        browseable = yes
        writeable = yes
        directory mask = 0775
        create mask = 0775
        write list = PREMPROVSOL+administrator, root
        admin users = PREMPROVSOL+administrator, root
        force user = root

[printers]
        comment = Network Printers
        browseable = yes
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = yes
        guest ok = no
        create mask = 0700
```

I set up a GPP for deployment to my Win10 Clients and the printers show up fine on the workstations.  Problem I run into is when I print to the shared printer, I get a vague error (The Handle is Invalid).  Troubleshooting this for three straight days and I can't pinpoint a suitable answer to this issue.

My assumption through all of this, is that the driver is not getting loaded from the print server.  I know the drivers are there as I uploaded MOST CURRENT drivers through the AD Print Management app and properly tied them to their printers.  This conclusion was reached when I manually installed the print drivers on the local workstation - after which, printing worked as expected.

My goal here is to deploy the printers to the proper workstations and not have to worry about installing the drivers.

What am I doing incorrectly here?  Surely this can be done, but I have no definitive guide.

Comment: I'm commenting only because of your statement about having no definitive guide.  There is a guide here https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Automatic_Printer_Driver_Downloads_for_Windows_Clients but perhaps you've seen it already.

Comment: @Organic Marble - Yes - this was the first one I followed.